# How to use dialogbox in plain html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use Jquery in plain HTML, but in doing so I am unable to execute it.
I think I am missing some link

**Header**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">      </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css"></script>
```

**Script**

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#btnShare").click(function(){
         alert("Click executed");
         $( "#menu" ).menu();
     });
 });
```

Bottom I am having some code with `<li>` and `<ul>`.

I am trying this code in Notepad++ . I am able to get alert .
Can anyone help me.

Any help is helpful.

Comment: As you're editing it in Notepad++ I'm assuming you don't serve it using a webbrowser but simply open in from Explorer. Check if the browser location bar shows `file://`. In that case the `//code.jquery...` will expand to `file://code.jquery...` and can't be found. Change `//code.jquery...` into `http://code.jquery...` for both the CSS and JavaScript and see if it's fixed.

Comment: @ckuijjer Thanks , but still I am unable to get my menu, instead of menu I have tried using dialog also, NO ! I am able to get alert but dialog/Menu is not getting displayed.

Comment: As the `$('#menu').menu()` initializes the menu, it shows a regular unordered list `<ul><li>...` before doing this. I'm wondering why you want it to be initialized when clicking the `#btnShare`? What are you exactly trying to achieve with this code? Plus adding the html might be helpful

Comment: are your trying to open a `dialog` window when `btnShare` is clicked? if so change `$("#menu").menu();` to `$('#menu').dialog('open');` i think thats your issue if im understanding you right

Comment: here is a basic jsfiddle showing what i think your after http://jsfiddle.net/b5169j8L/

Comment: @Parody Thanks a lot its working now, Can you please drop it in ans below so that I can accept. Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: @ShopShop no worries fella glad to have helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are your trying to open a `dialog` window when `btnShare` is clicked?

if so change `$("#menu").menu();` to `$('#menu').dialog('open');`

i think thats your issue if im understanding you right

and here is a basic [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b5169j8L/) showing what I think your after

Answer (score 1):

> Try this.actually you added extra "});" tag

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#btnShare").click(function(){
alert("Click executed");
 $( "#menu" ).menu();
});
});
```

Comment: I am getting alert, but my menu is not getting displayed. If I have error I may not get alert also rite

Answer (score 0):

You are missing script tags

```
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $("#btnShare").click(function(){
   alert("Click executed");
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
     });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hey I have script tags ..., I am getting alert also... I think some prob with links

Comment: Ok. You can always open your browser debugger and see if everything is loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your Post.

Now you can see, you have one `});` to much.

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("#btnShare").click(function(){
         alert("Click executed");
         $( "#menu" ).menu();
     });
 });
```

It is always good for debuging, to format your Code. IDE's like PHP Storm can do this with one Key Combo.